# O(n) substring algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, substring, knuth-morris-pratt, rabin-karp

so i've been researching about substring searching algorithms and found out that most algorithms like the kmp and the rabin-karp algorithm need an extra amount of time complexity for preprocessing time before doing some string matching. is there any benefit in doing so? and why wouldn't they simply skip to the string matching instantly so that the big-O time complexity does not drop to O(m+n)?
I tried creating a substring algorithm that i believe is O(n) (please correct me if i'm wrong), by simply skipping the preprocessing time. And i'm wondering why do people don't do it this way instead, please refer to the C code below.

```
int search(char hay[], char needle[], int hayLen, int needleLen){
    int found;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < (hayLen - needleLen + 1)){
        if (hay[i] == needle[0]){
            found = 1;
            for (int j=0; j<needleLen; j++){
                if (hay[i] != needle[j]){
                    found = 0;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (found)
                return i - needleLen;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

edit:

removed the strlen function to avoid any unwanted time complexities

Comment: If you care about performance, the first thing you should do is take all those constant `strlen()` calls out of your loops and evaluate them once before entering any of the loops.

Comment: Not sure about Rabin-Karp, but KMP is efficient because the preprocessing allows it to skip ahead in the input and bypass many comparisons.

Comment: You're calling `strlen` an awful lot in here, which is pretty punishing for what should be performant code. Those values don't change. Capture them once at the start of the function into variables. Each `strlen()` call is *O(n)* by itself!

Comment: You end up with O(nm) time as you repeatedly iterator over 'needle' for every character in 'haystack'.  Imaging what happens if 'needle' is 'a...ab' and haystack is 'a...a' (both very long strings with many a's).  So much worse than O(n+m)

Comment: You don't need to pass in those values, you can always compute them.

Comment: How is this O(n)? What if your haystack is `"aaaaaaaaaaaa"` and your needle is `"aaaaaab"` ?

Comment: If m<=n, O(n+m) is just O(n). And if you have the lengths as you show, you can ensure that m<=n by using `if (needleLen>hayLen) return -1;`).

Comment: But the algorithm proposed is O(mn) unless I am missing something

Comment: I was replying to the OP's question, not Engene's comment

Comment: @EugeneSh. `i` is incremented in every loop so it won't do more than `hayLen - needleLen + 1` loops

Comment: @user3386109 - point made.  i should have read it more carefully,  Thanks

Comment: You are mistaken about KMP being O(n+m). KMP is O(n), even when the lengths aren't provided. RK can also be made O(n) even when the lengths aren't provided, but that would slow it down when m<=n, which is basically always. But if m<=n is basically always true, then there's no need for the check because it's effectively already O(n) anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Honestly not a terrible question.  I think most of us have tried making a solution like this when trying to make a string-finding algorithm before discovering KMP.  The answer is that this greedy algorithm doesn’t work — it never goes backwards in `i`.  You may think “aha!  this is the start of the needle!”  and progress forwards until discovering “uh-oh!  this isn’t the whole needle!”.  In this algorithm, we then progress only forwards, continuing to search for the start of the needle.  However, the start of the actual needle may have been what you thought was a middle character while trying to greedily match as much of the needle as possible.

For example, `aab` and `aaab`.  It’s not until the third `a` that you realize “uh-oh, this isn’t the needle after all”, and a thorough O(nm) algorithm then starts again from the second position, but your algorithm just marches forward, and never realizes the `aab` that starts on the second position.  KMP solves this by kind of noting which parts of the needle in the middle could also be potential starting points for the needle.

Comment: Re "*Honestly not a terrible question.*", Well, except that the OP misses the point that O(n+m) just means O(n) in this context (since m will always be less than n when the lengths are provided), so an O(n) algorithm wouldn't have a lower complexity.

Comment: @ikegami Nothing wrong with your comment but it's not required that m is less than n. Even O(n + n) is O(n)

Comment: @4386427, Indeed, I meant less than or equal (and said so earlier, above).

Comment: @ikegami "since m will always be less than n when the lengths are provided" --> it depends on how the lengths are determined.  It could be as you say or O(n+m).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I said it's O(n) *when the lengths are provided* (because you can add `if (needleLen < hayLen) return -1;`)

Comment: Even when the lengths aren't provided, it can still be O(n). KMP is always O(n), and it would be easy to limit Rabin-Karp to O(n) even if C strings are provided without their length (by adding an O(n) to compare the lengths). It wouldn't be worth doing, though, because enforcing O(n) over O(m+n) would actually make the algorithm slower when m<=n, which is basically always.

Answer (score 5):

Well, your current code is O(n) but ...

Your code doesn't work!

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    char a[] = "aaaab";
    char b[] = "aaab";
    if (search(a, b, strlen(a), strlen(b)) != -1) 
        printf("OK\n"); 
    else 
        printf("FAIL\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously `b` can be found in `a` but your code says it isn't present.

The problem is that you always increment `i`. By doing that you do get O(n) but it also makes the code fail.

Comment: Thanks! finally a good explanation why people seem to use kmp or rabin-karp for substring search algorithms. I am trying to find a flaw on my algorithm and wondered why they wouldn't use this kind of algorithm instead.

Comment: This `main()` code is O(a+b) as `strlen(a), strlen(b)` are both called.  `strlen(b) <  strlen(a)` is discovered later, not a prerequisite here.  Code could use  `strlen(a), strnlen(b, strlen(a))` or the like to force O(a)

Answer (score 0):

> removed the strlen function to avoid any unwanted time complexities

You removed the `strlen` call(s), but now the length of the strings has to be passed into the function:

```
int search(char hay[], char needle[], int hayLen, int needleLen)
```

So... how does the complexity of the whole substring search change as the size of `needle` increases? After all, whether you calculate the length inside the function or outside the function, it still needs to be done. `O(m+n)` means that the complexity depends on the lengths of both `needle` and `haystack`.

To take the point to an extreme, you could write an O(1) `search` function by just adding a parameter that indicates the location of `needle` in `haystack`.